# what's the best way in Python to handle 3D arrays (matrices)

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, keras

I have a text file that contains a series of 2D matrices (8x10), organized by date, in this way:

```
#date_0
matrix 8x10
#date_1
matrix 8x10
...
#date_932
matrix 8x10
```

I would like to import this, in "something" like a data frame (MultiIndex ?), so I can have "something" with shape (933, 8, 10). All values are comma-separated, and I did read_csv ignoring the comments, so now I have a data frame of shape (7464, 11). There are 11 columns instead of 10 because each matrix looks like this:

```
#date_0
00,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,
10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,
.............................,
70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,
```

so after the last comma there is a /newLine and the 7464 is because 933x8.

Do you have any advice?
I need to use this (933, 8, 10) data set, together with another data set of shape (933, 1, 5), to do some regression/ML stuff. The other set is a time series of 933 5-dimensional vectors (one row and 5 columns).

Any advice is greatly appreciated, I am kind of new to Python and ML. Thanks

Comment: `...have a data frame of shape (7464, 11)` - Try reshaping the underlying values of the DataFrame: `a = df.to_numpy().reshape((933,8,10))`.

Comment: Or drop the last column of the DataFrame - `a = df.iloc[:,:-1].to_numpy().reshape((933,8,10))`.

Comment: Thanks! I had to update conda and pandas to get the "to_numpy()" function, then everything worked!